# how to list downloadable php5 modules (apt-get)

Tags: apt, php

There are many php modules that you can install using `apt-get install` (like php5-curl, php5-mysql, etc).

What is the command that will list all these available/downloadable php5 modules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `apt-cache search php5`

Comment: Don't forget about tab-completetion in the shell.

Answer (score 7):

Search all the packages whose name starts with "php5-":

```
apt-cache search --names-only ^php5-
```